# Facebook verification team can't login into test account

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We submitted our application for verification to Facebook, but were faced with the fact that the verification team could not log into the account.
The verification command always get the error: incorrect password.

We tried:

1. We provided different passwords for them to eliminate the mistake that they entered incorrectly.
2. They disabled double authentication on the account and gave me a password/email - they couldn’t log in. When contacting support, we found out that a person from another region cannot log into their account without double authentication.
3. I tried to login from the same region under vpn as verification team - it wasn't help.
4. We turned on authentication, gave them the code for otp, and email - they ignored it.
5. We gave them access from the mail and asked them to simply reset the password - they ignored it.
6. We tried to transfer another account - that didn’t help either.
7. They tried to login into application under their account, but application not in production now and they could not do this.

I wrote a total of 7 times just about this problem to support, and every time I get approximately the same answer - try transferring some other account, disable authentication, etc.

To be honest, I’m at a loss, my verification process lasts for a total of 5 months, and for the last 3 months they haven’t been able to log into my account.

Has anyone encountered this and knows how to solve it?

Comment: We are facing the same issue but on the bottom of the review, new button appeared for us. We are trying to solve their problem with our test account. Everybody can connect account expects testers. Can you check the bottom of review, is there any button to send messages to tester directly?

Comment: Do you mean Facebook App Review Support button? Can we by this send message direct to the verification team?

Comment: Yes, you can communicate with them. It’s still hard to understand them and their progress but you can try at least.